# Solving an initial value problem (PDE)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

$$∂u/∂x + ∂u/∂y = 1,$$

$$u(x,0) = \mathrm{e}^x$$

My prof hasn't explained how to solve these very well.  I think it has something to do with the method of characteristics, but I'm not entirely sure what that is or how to employ it.  I'd really appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very nicely explained in L. Evan's book "Partial differential equations", Chapter 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set 
$$
v(t)=u(t+c,t),
$$
then the PDE provides that
$$
v'(t)=u_x(t+c,t)+u_y(t+c,t)=1,
$$
and  thus
$$
v(t)=v(0)+t=u(c,0)+t=\mathrm{e}^c+t.
$$
Therefore, for every $c,t$
$$
u(t+c,t)=\mathrm{e}^c+t,
$$
and hence setting $x=t+c$, $y=t$, and thus $c=x-y$, we ontain:
$$
u(x,y)=\mathrm{e}^{x-y}+y,
$$
which is the unique solution of the Cauchy problem.